# Gapi.auth, why do I need to use ?onload callback parameter?

Tags: javascript, google-api, synchronous

I have this function (taken from the google getting started guide)

```
function checkAuth() {
  gapi.auth.authorize(
    {
      'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
      'scope': SCOPES.join(' '),
      'immediate': true
    }, handleAuthResult);
}
```

It executes correctly if I load the Google Api Client library like this

```
$.getScript("https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=checkAuth");
```

However I get a `can not call authorize of undefined` error if I try to execute the function as the callback of the $.getScript method, like this

```
$.getScript("https://apis.google.com/js/client.js", checkAuth);
```

But I do not understand why. Aren't both suppose to execute checkAuth() only once the Google Api Client library has completed loading? Anyone got any ideas why the 2nd approach isn't working?